# Predicting volume of building from CITYJSON polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, citygml

I must predict a volume of any selected multipolygon which is from a [CITYGML file](https://www.wien.gv.at/ma41datenviewer/downloads/ma41/geodaten/lod2_gml/104083_lod2_gml.zip) that was converted to CITYJSON with [citygmltools 1.4.2](https://github.com/citygml4j/citygml-tools/releases/tag/v1.4.2) and loaded with CITYJSON Loader Plugin in QGIS 3.20.0. I can see the buildings in 3D view. I tried the plugin Volume Calculation Tool  but it outputs nothing.

How can I calculate the volume of such selected polygon?

Comment: Which CRS is your data in? What exactly happens when you run the volume calculation? Why did you resort to using a plugin, when there are native tools available?

Comment: CRS is: EPSG:31256 - MGI / Austria GK East. Can you please write the explanation of how to use native tools as an answer? I am new to QGIS. The plugin just puts out a 0 in the console.

Comment: That data looks weird. Usually I'd say "multiply area by height", but many features don't have an obvious height value, but several instead. I suggest you do some research at the providers homepage first, before trying to calculate stuff.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/404323/115.

Comment: @PolyGeo it is not as the question can not be deleted and that question was downvoted twice and has no chance of being answered.

Comment: @Erik most objects are mutlipolygons with complicated geometries (LOD2). Any idea on how to calculate such volume?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: i added an explanation of multipolygon in comment, my question is clear..